# Is there any spreadsheet which use a formula repository instead of writing several copies directly in the cell?

Tags: architecture, spreadsheet, dataflow, concept

I like speradsheet programs, but there is a disturbing thing with them: the formulas must be entered in the cells. It has several withdraws:

- I need to scan thru *all the cells* to see, what's going in a sheet;
- if I change a formula, I must copy it to several cells;
- of course, sometimes I forget copy new formulas into *all* the cells;
- it eats up lot of space, the same long formula is repeated several times.

**Have you ever seen a spreadsheet software which has a kind of formula repository?** Does it exists?

(I'm working now on a spreadsheet software, which is more specialized than desktop spreadsheets, and I'm using one formula per row - that's where the question comes.)

Also, spreadsheets are dataflow systems, and it's strange, that there are no pre-made reusable components, which is the base concept of dataflow systems. In spreadsheets, all components are used once, which is very bad design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lotus Improv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lotus_Improv) did this.

Answer (score 1):

Since Office 2007, MS Excel has supported named formulae, which can be held at workbook- or worksheet- level, and can subsequently be used in many cells.

See this [link](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/newsgroups/dynamic_charts/named_formulas.html) or [this](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/msoffice/?p=636) for an explanation

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.fast-standard.org/ and be prepared to be amazed at how powerful and easy Excel is when used following a focussed methodology.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Excel allows Visual Basic for Applications that can do exactly this.  You write code that can scan all the cells and run formulas on them.

Comment: Do you think an average user will create such a sheet?